# Unusual conversion error (string to integer) asp.net

Tags: asp.net, string, types, integer

I have my repeater item template:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Linksrepeater" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate><h2>Links</h2><ul>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<li><%#Container.DataItem("Category")%></li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</ul>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Hooked up to:

```
s = "sql"
        x = New SqlCommand(s, c)
        x.Parameters.Add("@contentid", SqlDbType.Int)
        x.Parameters("@contentid").Value = contentid
        c.Open()
        r = x.ExecuteReader
        If r.HasRows Then
            Linksrepeater.DataSource = r
            Linksrepeater.DataBind()
        End If

        c.Close()
        r.Close()
```

When I run the code I get:

> Invalid Cast Exception was not handled by user code (Conversion from
>   string "category" to type 'Integer' is not valid.)

I'm not sure how / why it is trying to convert `Category` to integer as in the db it is a string.

Can you please tell me how to avoid this error? thanks.

EDIT:

The same error occurs if I try `<%#Container.DataItem("URL")%>`

Comment: Going to need a full code sample here, including the SQL string.

Comment: Yeah, what you think works is probably what is not working, that is why you are here, right? ;-) post the sql and the markup for the repeater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this snippet is correct?

```
<%# Container.DataItem("Category") %>
```

Try this instead:

```
<%# Eval("Category") %>
```

or (changing MyObject to your class name)

```
<%# (Container.DataItem as MyObject).Category %>
```